# Javascript to update Stripe product image based on Product ID hits the error

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script, stripe-payments

I am trying to use Stripe API to update Stripe product image based on Product ID.

I have created a Google sheet with two columns

```
ProductId           ImageUrl
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
prod_PV3k2gGM3GrmqO https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/sketch-plain-travelling_1308-86639.jpg
prod_PV3kLlPyxmwcy7 https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/sketch-plain-travelling_1308-86639.jpg
prod_PV3kubG9uCMsFR https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/sketch-plain-travelling_1308-86639.jpg
```

And I have the following code in Google's Action Script:

```
// Define your Stripe API key here
const STRIPE_API_KEY = 'hidden';

function insertImageIntoStripeProduct() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    const productId = data[i][0]; // Assuming ProductID is in the first column
    const imageUrl = data[i][1]; // Assuming ImageURL is in the second column

    if (productId && imageUrl) {
      updateStripeProduct(productId, imageUrl);
    }
  }
}

function updateStripeProduct(productId, imageUrl) {
  const apiUrl = `https://api.stripe.com/v1/products/${productId}`;
  const productData = {
    images: [imageUrl],
  };

  makeStripeRequest(apiUrl, 'POST', productData);
}

function makeStripeRequest(apiUrl, method, requestData) {
  const formData = Object.entries(requestData)
    .map(([key, value]) => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`)
    .join('&');

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, {
    method,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${STRIPE_API_KEY}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    payload: formData,
  });

  if (response.getResponseCode() !== 200) {
    throw new Error(`Stripe API Error: ${response.getContentText()}`);
  }

  return JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
}
```

However, after execution it hit following error:

```
Exception: Request failed for https://api.stripe.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid array",
    "param": "images",
    "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs/req_Ux1hF7z4QsOtZ1?... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
makeStripeRequest   @ Code.gs:32
updateStripeProduct @ Code.gs:24
insertImageIntoStripeProduct    @ Code.gs:13
```

Can you please help me modifying this code, so that it works?

Thank you in advance.

Best,

Roman

I tried using ChatGPT. It provided dozens of modifications of the code, but none of them worked.

Comment: Can you provide the official document of the method of the API you want to use? Can I think that your authorization of `Bearer ${STRIPE_API_KEY}` is valid for using your API?

Comment: Here is the product objects: https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/object and yes API key is correct.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `yes API key is correct.`, I understood that `Bearer ${STRIPE_API_KEY}` is a valid value. I will check your provided URL. If I find the document of the specification of the method of this API you want to use, I would like to try to think of a solution.

Comment: Thank you, Tanaike. Yes, Bearer ${STRIPE_API_KEY} is a valid value as i am successfully using it for other projects. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed 4 modification patterns as an answer. Please confirm it. But, I cannot test them. So, if those were not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Like what the error message mentions, you're probably not passing in an array of strings in `images` as required by the Stripe API [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/object#product_object-images). If you check the corresponding [request in the Stripe Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs/req_Ux1hF7z4QsOtZ1) as listed in `request_log_url`, you can see the value being passed in and modify your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw your provided URL and your showing script, I guessed that you might have wanted to use [Update a product](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/update). If my understanding is correct, it seems that in the case of `images`, the value is `[]`.

In this case, if multiple query parameters like `images="http://###"&images="http://###"`, the request is run with `images=["http://###","http://###"]`. But, in the case of a single query parameter like `images="http://###"`, I think that the request is run with `images="http://###"`. I think that this is the same with your showing script. But, in your situation, an error occurs. An error `"Invalid array"` occurs at `"images"`.

From the above situation, by my guess, I would like to propose the following 4 modification patterns. Please test them.

#### Pattern 1:

##### From:

```
images: [imageUrl],
```

##### To:

```
"images[]": imageUrl,
```

- In the case of `"images[]": imageUrl,`, `images` is `images%5B%5D=http%3A%2F%2F###`. It's `images[]=http://###`.

#### Pattern 2:

##### From:

```
images: [imageUrl],
```

##### To:

```
images: JSON.stringify([imageUrl]),
```

- In the case of `images: JSON.stringify([imageUrl]),`, `images` is `images=%5B%22http%3A%2F%2F###%22%5D`. It's `images=["http://###"]`.

#### Pattern 3:

##### From:

```
images: [imageUrl],
```

##### To:

```
images: `[${imageUrl}]`,
```

- In the case of `images:` [${imageUrl}]`,`, `images` is `images=%5Bhttp%3A%2F%2Faaa%5D`. It's `images=[http://aaa]`.

#### Pattern 4:

##### From:

```
const formData = Object.entries(requestData)
  .map(([key, value]) => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`)
  .join('&');
```

##### To:

```
const formData = Object.entries(requestData)
  .map(([key, value]) => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`)
  .join('&') + "&images";
```

- In this pattern, please don't modify `images: [imageUrl],`, and modify your script as follows.
- In the case of `images: [imageUrl],` and `.join('&') + "&images";`, `images` is `images=http%3A%2F%2F###&images`. It's `images=http://###&images`.

#### Note:

- In these modifications, it supposes that your URL and your authorization of `Authorization: Bearer ${STRIPE_API_KEY}`, work. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Dear Tanaike, The first pattern you proposed did the job just fine! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Roman Patelev Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.